# Gnuplot line types

Tags: gnuplot

How do I draw different types of lines on gnuplot? I got to draw different colors. My script joins several files and I think it is why the lines are not dash. Only two of four are dashed.
Thanks
Felipe

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

set grid
set title 'Estado dos arquivos no BTRIM com peers de comportamento condicionado'
set xlabel 'Tempo discreto'
set ylabel 'Quantidade de arquivos'
set style line 1 lc rgb '#0060ad' lt 1 lw 2 pi -1 ps 1.0
set style line 2 lc rgb '#dd181f' lt 9 lw 2 pi -1 ps 1.0
set style line 3 lc rgb '#29c524' lt 6 lw 2 pi -1 ps 1.0
set style line 4 lc rgb '#7D72F9' lt 7 lw 2 pi -1 ps 1.0
set style line 5 lc rgb '#000000' lt 8 lw 2 pi -1 ps 1.0

set termoption dashed
#set pointintervalbox 0
#set boxwidth 0.1
#set style fill solid

plot '<paste ../00/StatisticNormal.txt ../01/StatisticNormal.txt ../02/StatisticNormal.txt  ../03/StatisticNormal.txt ../04/StatisticNormal.txt ../05/StatisticNormal.txt ../06/StatisticNormal.txt ../07/StatisticNormal.txt ../08/StatisticNormal.txt ../09/StatisticNormal.txt' smooth unique with line ls 1 title 'Normais', \
'<paste ../00/StatisticVogue.txt ../01/StatisticVogue.txt ../02/StatisticVogue.txt ../03/StatisticVogue.txt ../04/StatisticVogue.txt ../05/StatisticVogue.txt ../06/StatisticVogue.txt ../07/StatisticVogue.txt ../08/StatisticVogue.txt ../09/StatisticVogue.txt' smooth unique with line ls 2 title 'na Moda', \
'<paste ../00/StatisticPopular.txt ../01/StatisticPopular.txt ../02/StatisticPopular.txt ../03/StatisticPopular.txt ../04/StatisticPopular.txt ../05/StatisticPopular.txt ../06/StatisticPopular.txt ../07/StatisticPopular.txt ../08/StatisticPopular.txt ../09/StatisticPopular.txt' smooth unique with line ls 3 title 'Populares', \
'<paste ../00/StatisticRarity.txt ../01/StatisticRarity.txt ../02/StatisticRarity.txt ../03/StatisticRarity.txt ../04/StatisticRarity.txt ../05/StatisticRarity.txt ../06/StatisticRarity.txt ../07/StatisticRarity.txt ../08/StatisticRarity.txt ../09/StatisticRarity.txt' smooth unique with line ls 4 title 'Raros'

pause -1
```

Comment: So was that your solution? If you use `lc` in a line style definition, the `lt` part is only to choose the dash type. This depends on the terminal. To see the supported dash types, and with which linetype they are associated with, just use the `test` command, like e.g. `set terminal pngcairo dashed; set output 'test.png'; test; set output` or similar with any other terminal type.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

## Until version 4.6

The dash type of a `linestyle` is given by the `linetype`, which does also select the line color unless you explicitely set an other one with `linecolor`.

However, the support for dashed lines depends on the selected terminal:

1. Some terminals don't support dashed lines, like `png` (uses `libgd`)
2. Other terminals, like `pngcairo`, support dashed lines, but it is disables by default. To enable it, use `set termoption dashed`, or `set terminal pngcairo dashed ...`.
3. The exact dash patterns differ between terminals. To see the defined `linetype`, use the `test` command:

Running

```
set terminal pngcairo dashed
set output 'test.png'
test
set output
```

gives:

[image]

whereas, the `postscript` terminal shows different dash patterns:

```
set terminal postscript eps color colortext
set output 'test.eps'
test
set output
```

[image]

## Version 5.0

Starting with version 5.0 the following changes related to linetypes, dash patterns and line colors are introduced:

- A new `dashtype` parameter was introduced:

  To get the predefined dash patterns, use e.g.

  ```
  plot x dashtype 2
  ```

  You can also specify custom dash patterns like

  ```
  plot x dashtype (3,5,10,5),\
       2*x dashtype '.-_'
  ```
- The terminal options `dashed` and `solid` are ignored. By default all lines are solid. To change them to dashed, use e.g.

  ```
  set for [i=1:8] linetype i dashtype i
  ```
- The default set of line colors was changed. You can select between three different color sets with `set colorsequence default|podo|classic`:

[image]

Comment: This is a very useful post

Comment: @Phonon you can define more linetypes and then use `set linetype cycle 20`

Comment: Thanks, but how do you define more linetypes?

Comment: `set linetype 10 lc rgb '#4488bb' dt (5, 5, 10, 10)`, `set linetype 11 ...` and so on

Comment: Link for adding dashed lines in to termtype x11 gnuplot 4.6 here:
   https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/octave-maintainers/2012-12/msg00363.html

After following this I see dashed lines in the termtype x11 test.

Comment: It would be helpful to get at least a warning message from gnuplot about png terminal not supporting dashed lines... Switching to pngcairo did the trick.

Comment: 1000x thanks for the "test" command. I've been using gnuplot for >25 years now but I never came across this one. This would have saved me hours in trying different line types/styles etc.