# How can the plot symbol be specified in the ruby implementation of gnuplot?

Tags: ruby, gnuplot

The default plot symbol for an x,y dataset is a red cross. Let's say I'd like it to be a filled, black square. How do I do that?

To be transparent about what I'm doing in this code example, I set up a plot using gnuplot at the (already-specified) output path. It's a png, with a specified size, font and fontsize. I fiddle a bit with the left margin and border thickness and give my axes some titles, but those are other aesthetics.

To generate black lines, I would uncomment that one commented line. How do I get, say, filled squares though? I cannot work it out from the gnuplot documentation at http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.6/gnuplot.pdf

```
  ::Gnuplot.open do |gp|
    ::Gnuplot::Plot.new(gp) do |plot|
      plot.terminal "png size 1800,600 font \"arial,20\""
      plot.lmargin "10"
      plot.output "#{star[:wrapped_rv_plot]}"
      plot.border "linewidth 2"
      plot.ylabel "Radial velocity (km/s)"
      plot.xlabel "Orbital Phase"

      x = ext_phase_rv.map { |point| point[0] }
      y = ext_phase_rv.map { |point| point[1] }

      plot.data << ::Gnuplot::DataSet.new([x, y]) do |ds|
        # ds.with = "lines lt rgb \"black\""
        ds.notitle
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get squared points with `linetype 5`, see e.g. [Gnuplot line types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19420678/2604213). To plot with points, use `with points` :)

```
ds.with = "points"
ds.linecolor = "rgb 'blue' linetype 5"
```

Comment: That didn't quite do it, but it led me along the right track. Particularly with the reference to the test page. Thanks!

Comment: For me it works fine, of course I tested it before answering! The current version of the [ruby gnuplot gem](https://github.com/rdp/ruby_gnuplot/blob/master/lib/gnuplot.rb) even allows you to use `ds.linestyle` and define proper line styles.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the commented line with the code below will produce black squares. Please see Christoph's answer for a link to more 'pt' (point type) examples.

```
ds.with = "points lc rgb 'black' pt 5"
```