# clear differentiation of throughputs in gnuplot

Tags: linux, plot, gnuplot, throughput, iperf

I'm comparing the throughput of wireless link in two situations, i want to plot them both in a single graph. the problem is that the graph obtained by plotting throughput against time is as in this picture

[image: first graph]

when i plot both throughputs in the same graph i obtain something as in this second picture [image: second graph]    it is not clear to differentiate between the two.

I've used this code below for plotting a single throughput graph

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

reset

!iperf -c 192.168.1.101 -i 0.5 -t 60 > a

#this is used for deleting first 6 lines 
!sed -i 1,+5d a

#used to delete last line
!sed '$d' a > cropped

!cat cropped | cut -c 7-10 > b
!cat cropped | cut -c 35-38 > c
!paste b c > d

!awk 'BEGIN{print "0.0  0.0"}{print}' d > e

set xlabel "time"
set ylabel "throughput"

set terminal png nocrop enhanced font arial 8 size 900,300
#set terminal png size 900, 300

set output "chart_1.png"

#table name below graph(naming curve by colour)
set key below

plot  'e' using 1:2 title "Throughput Performance" with lines
```

below is the code which i have used for plotting both graphs

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

reset



set xlabel "time"
set ylabel "throughput"


set terminal png nocrop enhanced font arial 8 size 900,300
#set terminal png size 900, 300

set output "chart_1.png"


#table name below graph(naming curve by colour)
set key below



set style data linespoints

plot "1" using 1:2 title "case1", \
     "2" using 1:2 title "case2"
```

output looks like this: [image]

Comment: where's the code for the "both" version?

Comment: Two general tips: use the `pngcairo` terminal if you need a pixel-based format and plot `with lines` (the two graphs together were plot `with linespoints`, or one only `with points`). And, the visualization depends on what you want to emphasize. You could also draw two graphs one above the other with `set multiplot layout 2,1`, mark some regions of special interest, indlude a grid etc.

Comment: i edited the post and added the code i have used to plot both graphs.. is it possible to make the curves more normalized?

Comment: What do you mean with "more normalized"? You can apply some smoothing operations like `plot "1" using 1:2 smooth csplines` or similar, see `help smooth`.

Comment: Yes Smoothing is what i wanted..it looks much better now to distinguish between two.. thank you christoph :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general remark first: Use the `pngcairo` terminal which provides much better antialiasing.

For processing of your data you can use different smoothing options, like `smooth csplines`, `smooth bezier` or similar (see e.g. `help smooth` in the interactive gnuplot terminal):

```
plot "1" using 1:2 smooth csplines, "2" using 1:2 smooth csplines
```

Which smoothing variant you use depend again on the meaning of your data.

What could also help, is to use other point types then the default ones, e.g. `pt 1` for the first and `pt 7` for the second one, see [Gnuplot line types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412382/gnuplot-line-types) for the use of the `test` command to check the available point types.