# Can't Change the Line Type in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I use the following command:

```
gnuplot> plot x**2 lt 2 pt 4 lc 7 pi -6, x**3 lt 6 pt 8 lc 7 pi -6
```

But the output is like so:
[image]

As you can see, `pt` and `lc` commands work but `lt` does not.
How can I change my line type between dashed, dotted, etc.?

Comment: When I run that command, I get a series of warnings. What other commands have you run before that and what terminal are you using?

Comment: @TomFenech I'm using wxt in Windows 8.1

Comment: Do you not get any warnings? I'm using the wxt terminal as well and I get warnings like "No pointtype/pointinterval specifier allowed". What version of gnuplot are you using?

Comment: I get no warnings. I'm using the latest version [gnuplot 4.6.5](http://www.gnuplot.info/announce_4.6.5.txt)

Comment: I had to do `set style function linespoints` before plotting. I'm not sure why you're having a problem with `lt` if you're using the wxt terminal though, it works fine for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gnuplot line types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412382/gnuplot-line-types)

Comment: Please see [Gnuplot line types](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19412382/2604213) for a detailled description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminal you are using provides solid lines only. Try a different terminal or terminal settings (dashed may work, see 'help set terminal *yourterminal*').

You may check the available styles with the command *test*.

Good luck!