# Predefined point types in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

How do I set up predefined point styles in Gnuplot? Since I am colorblind and I really dislike the standard colors of Gnuplot (colors 3 4 and 5 are blue, blue and blue for me), I made a list in a .gnuplot file in my home directory with some more friendly colors. This file looks like this

```
set style line 1 lt 5 lw 5 lc rgb "red"
set style line 2 lt 6 lw 5 lc rgb "blue"
set style line 3 lt 2 lw 5 lc rgb "olive"
set style line 4 lt 3 lw 5 lc rgb "salmon"
set style line 5 lt 4 lw 5 lc rgb "black"
...
```

But when I want to plot data points, it uses the same original Gnuplot colors. Is there a way to define points in the same way as these lines? For example, the first point type are black boxes and the second are red triangles etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With such a file you must either explicitely specify the respective line style with

```
load 'mycolors.gp'
plot x linestyle 1, 2*x linestyle 2
```

or you use `set style increment user` which should automatically use line styles instead of line types:

```
load 'mycolors.gp'
set style increment user
plot x, 2*x
```

But beware, that using `set style increment user` is deprecated.

In your case, the best option is to redefine directly the linetypes:

```
set linetype 1 lt 5 lw 5 lc rgb "red"
set linetype 2 lt 6 lw 5 lc rgb "blue"
set linetype 3 lt 2 lw 5 lc rgb "olive"

plot x, 2*x, 3*x
```

As side note: you must keep in mind that `set linetype` is not affected by `reset`.

You may also want to try out the colors defined in the files `share/colors_default.gp` and `share/colors_podo.gp`, which are shipped with the gnuplot binary (see the last image on [Gnuplot line types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19420678/2604213) to see how these look like).