# How to add numbers of the column to the circle on the gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

How to put numbers of column one of the file on the circles:

```
plot 'alias_SCN' using 2:3 with circles
```

This is some of **alias_SCN** entreis

```
1 50 91.66
2 45 83.66
3 55 83.66
4 40 75
5 50 75
6 60 75
7 35 83.66
8 65 83.66
9 25 83.66
10 30 75
```

Now what I am looking for is to put the numbers of column one on related circle.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `test` command to find out which points are supported for each terminal (see e.g. [Gnuplot line types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19420678/2604213)). For the `wxt` terminal you can use `pointtype 6`.

To put a label above the point, use the `labels` plotting style

```
plot 'alias_SCN' using 2:3:(sprintf('%d', $1)) with labels offset 0,1 point pointtype 6 pointsize 2
```

If you want more control over the circles, you can also use the `circles` plotting style, in which case you must use two plot commands to get also the labels:

```
plot 'alias_SCN' using 2:3:(0.2) with circles,\
     '' using 2:3:(sprintf('%d', $1)) with labels offset 0,1
```

The third column for the circles gives the radius, here a fixed radius of `0.2`.

Comment: How can I access the color of circles ? would you please add that to your answer?

Comment: E.g. with `linecolor rgb '#cc3300'`. You'll find a lot of answers here about gnuplot and linecolor.