# How to draw a rectangle with a colored border in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, rectangles

I would like to draw an empty rectangle in my plot.

So far I have:

```
set style rect back fs empty border lt 3 
set object 1 rect from 1,1 to 2,2
```

And I have my rectangle with a dashed line. How do I change the color of the line? lc does not seem to work after border. I also tried with setting a new line style, and border but I was not successful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `lc` instead of `lt` in the code you posted works fine with version 4.6.5:

```
reset
set style rect back fs empty border lc rgb '#008800'
set object 1 rect from 1,1 to 2,2 lw 5
set object 2 rect from 1,3 to 2,4 lw 5 fs empty border lc rgb '#880088'
plot x
```

[image]

In any case (both with `lt 3` and `lc ...`) the rectangle borders are solid. I tried the `wxt`, `pngcairo`, `pdfcairo` and `postscript` terminals and set the `dashed` option every time.

Comment: it worked also in epslatex.. but what do you mean set the `dashed` option? can i still have the lines dashed?

Comment: The difference between the epslatex and the postscript terminals consists only in the text rendering. All other parts are identical. For the `dashed` terminal option, see e.g. [Gnuplot line types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412382/gnuplot-line-types/19420678#19420678). Rectangle borders are always solid with gnuplot version 4.6.x, but the behavior is fixed for 5.0, see http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1460/.

Comment: ok, so at the moment I can't have both (colored and dashed) in a rectangle (I did it in the end by modifying the borders in inkscape). Thank you again