# Gnuplot - rectangles as objects outside graph area?

Tags: gnuplot, rectangles

I would like get something like this:

Rectangle outside graph:

[image]

Could I get that with `set object <number> rect` ? Or is this only to draw rectangles inside graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the `screen` coordinates (which refer to the entire window) like so:

```
set object 1 rect from screen 0.0, screen 0.9 to screen 0.1, screen 1.0
```

this would create a rectangle in the top left 10% of the plotting window

Comment: And how could I make dashed borders?

Comment: that [rectangle with colored border](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406577/how-to-draw-a-rectangle-with-a-colored-border-in-gnuplot) was helpful, thanks anyway :D

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in @ewcz's answer, you can use screen coordinates for drawing objects (partly) outside the graph area .
However, if you check `help object` and you will find the option `noclip` at least since gnuplot 4.6.5. (default is `clip`).

With this you can draw objects outside the graph using, e.g. graph, first, second, etc. coordinates as well (check `help coordinates`), especially in case you want to adjust the size of your rectangle to graph or x/y-coordinates.

**Script:**

```
### draw rectangle outside graph area
reset session

set xrange [0:20]
set yrange [0:10]

set xlabel "x-axis"
set ylabel "y-axis"
set origin 0.1, 0.1
set size   0.8, 0.8

set obj 1 rect noclip from graph -0.1, 0.9 to graph 0.1, 1.1 
set obj 1 fs empty border rgb "red" lw 2 dt 4

set obj 2 rect noclip from first -2,-2 to first 7,3
set obj 2 fs empty border rgb "green" lw 2 dt 1

set obj 3 rect noclip from screen 0.6,0.6 to screen 1,1
set obj 3 fs empty border rgb "blue" lw 2 dt 3

plot x
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]