# I don't have color on my .eps figure using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, osx-mavericks, eps

I want to trace some curves with gnuplot. I recently change my computer and now I have a MacOSX 10.9.5
In my other computer, colors appeared in my .eps figure, but with my Mac not anymore, and an error message appears : "· Times not found, using Courier." which is an other problem I think.
My gnuplot version is Version 5.0 patchlevel 0.

Here is my trace.p that I load with gnuplot with

$ gnuplot

gnuplot > load "trace.p"

```
set autoscale
unset logscale
unset label
set term postscript enhanced 'Times'
set output"E_Hxc_bath_exact_weak.eps"
set title "E^{bath,exact}_{Hxc}/U, E^{bath,weak}_{Hxc}/U functions of U/t with potential more or equal to second-order set to 0"
set xlabel "U/t"
set ylabel "E^{bath}_{Hxc}/U"
set xrange [0.7:10]
set yrange [-7:10]
set key left top
set style line 1 lt 1 lc rgb "red" lw 3
set style line 2 lt 2 lc rgb "red" lw 3
set style line 3 lt 3 lc rgb "red" lw 3
set style line 4 lt 1 lc rgb "green" lw 3
set style line 5 lt 2 lc rgb "green" lw 3
set style line 6 lt 3 lc rgb "green" lw 3
set style line 7 lt 1 lc rgb "black" lw 3
set style line 8 lt 2 lc rgb "black" lw 3
set style line 9 lt 1 lc rgb "blue" lw 3
set style line 10 lt 2 lc rgb "blue" lw 3
set style line 11 lt 3 lc rgb "blue" lw 3
set style line 12 lt 1 lc rgb "violet" lw 3
set style line 13 lt 2 lc rgb "violet" lw 3

plot (0.25 - (3/4)/(sqrt(1+64/(x**2)) + 2*sqrt(1+16/(x**2)))) with lines ls 7 title "exact", (0.25 - 3*(x**2)/64 + (x**3)/(2*16*16)) with lines ls 1 title "weak";
```

Some lines are certainly useless, but I don't know why the result is colorless, maybe I miss an application or something...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding the `color` flag to the `set term` line in your script.

Comment: Indeed, simple as that... Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

For the dashed lines which didn't appear, it is because in version 5.0, the command change, it is no more linetype but dashtype.

See the response of [Gnuplot line types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412382/gnuplot-line-types) for more precision.