# gnuplot - Wrong default colours for curves

Tags: colors, gnuplot, curves

I have recently installed gnuplot on my mac and I am having troubles in managing the curves options correctly:

- the default **colours** are completely mismatched
- the **dashed** or **dotted** commands seem not to respond (thickness works fine though)
- this happens also for the **mesh** of the surface 3d plots (colours of the surface are OK though)
- the problem persists using different terminals (I mainly use X11) and so different output files (I need eps)

This is a ***basic example*** of what I get (I am now allowed to upload image, sorry):

```
plot sin(x) lc 1 lw 3 lt 3
```

I get the wrong colour of curve: the curve should be **red** while it shows **purple**

Comment: If you are using gnuplot 5: this is intentional, see my answer to [Gnuplot line types](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19420678/2604213) for an explanation of the changed color and dashtype handling.