# Different dashtype in the same plot (Gnuplot 4.6.6)

Tags: line, gnuplot, legend, linestyle

I am using **epscairo** terminal.

I have 10 lines in one plot and I defined line styles such as:

set style line 1 linetype 1 lw 1 linecolor rgb 'black'

set style line 2 linetype 2 lw 1 linecolor rgb 'black'

set style line 3 linetype 3 lw 1 linecolor rgb 'black'

set style line 4 linetype 4 lw 1 linecolor rgb 'black'

set style line 5 linetype 5 lw 1 linecolor rgb 'black'

set style line 6 linetype 6 lw 1 linecolor rgb 'black'

set style line 7 linetype 7 lw 1 linecolor rgb 'black'

set style line 8 linetype 8 lw 1 linecolor rgb 'black'

set style line 9 linetype 9 lw 1 linecolor rgb 'black'

set style line 10 linetype 10 lw 1 linecolor rgb 'black'

---

I want all the lines to be black as it is set.

**Epscairo** terminal repeats line patters each 6th line, i.e. :
- linetype 6 is the same as linetype 1 if do not change color or thickness
- linetype 7 is the same as linetype 2 if do not change color or thickness
- etc.

I read this topic but it didn't help:
[Gnuplot line types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412382/gnuplot-line-types)

I want to use different dashtypes (if that is the option) in the same plot, for example from 1-5 I want to use dashes, and from 6-10 I want to use symbols (squares, circles, triangles etc).

Is that possible and how can I do that?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Well, you have five different dash types in the line styles 1..5. To have symbols in the plots 6...10 you must plot those `with points`.

Comment: That is precisely my question, how do I use that command?
Adding "...pointtype #number" changes nothing, but it also don't return error?

Example:
set style line 6 linetype 6 lw 1 pointtype 8 linecolor rgb 'black'

Comment: Using e.g. `set style line 6 pt 8 lc rgb 'black'; plot x ls 6 with points` works fine: http://i.stack.imgur.com/L1qs4.png

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out now!