# Dashed lines with markers in gnuplot 4.6

Tags: gnuplot, postscript, eps

I am trying to plot my data using gnuplot 4.6 and I'd like to have dashed lines with markers for some data, while using postscript environment for the output. When I define a line style and use it to plot the data, The output has only the markers.

```
set terminal postscript eps color enhanced dl 3
set out "out.eps"
set style line 1 lt 2 lc rgb "red" pt 7 ps 0.750
plot 'data.dat' u 1:2 ls 1
```

This gives only the marker *pt 7* without the dashed lines. But when I plot the same data without defining any line style, but specifying the options along with *plot* command, both marker and dashed lines are present in the output.

```
set terminal postscript eps color enhanced dl 3
set out "out.eps"
plot 'data.dat' u 1:2 w lp lt 2 pt 11 ps 1
```

**I get dashed lines only when I specify linetype along with plot command, but not while defining it as part of the line style.** Can anyone explain why is this so?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19420678/2604213

Comment: @Christoph I had already seen the post. The problem which I encounter is that when I specify linetype along with a linestyle definition, the dashed lines are not seen.

Comment: The answer I linked to contains detailed information. For gnuplot version 4.6 you are simply missing the `dashed` terminal option.