# How to do several key in one line in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to get several keys from the graphs in one line in gnuplot as shown in the attached image

[image]

---

here is an example of the code:

```
set key maxrows 2
plot sin(x) title 'x1',cos(x) title 'x2',x title' ',2*x title ' ',-x title ' ',-3*x title ' '
```

I get this result (see attached). my question how to obtain the 3 key blow 'green - pink -yellow' dashed line

[image]

Comment: Pls be more precise, show us your code and data.

Answer (score 1):

You could [set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19420678/5351549) the dashtype (assuming that your terminal supports it):

```
set key maxrows 2

plot \
   sin(x) dt 1 title 'x1', cos(x) dt 3 title 'x2', \
   x dt 1 title ' ', 2*x dt 3 title ' ', \
  -x dt 1 title ' ', -3*x dt 3 title ' '
```

Comment: option 'dt' not recognized by gnuplot 4.6