# gnuplot dashed lines are not plotted in color

Tags: plot, gnuplot, visualization

I've been searching for quite some time how to plot dashed lines in gnuplot 5.2, and I've tried some code which was supposed to plot dashed lines, but to no avail. Can someone please help me understand what is wrong in my code that does not allow plotting dashed lines?

```
reset session
set term pngcairo dashed
set output 'dashcolor_1.png'
set label 1 "set style line 1 lt 2 lc rgb \"red\" lw 3" at -0.4, -0.25, 0 left norotate back textcolor rgb "red"  nopoint offset character 0, 0, 0
set label 2 "set style line 2 lt 2 lc rgb \"orange\" lw 2" at -0.4, -0.35, 0 left norotate back textcolor rgb "orange"  nopoint offset character 0, 0, 0
set label 3 "set style line 3 lt 2 lc rgb \"yellow\" lw 3" at -0.4, -0.45, 0 left norotate back textcolor rgb "yellow"  nopoint offset character 0, 0, 0
set label 4 "set style line 4 lt 2 lc rgb \"green\" lw 2" at -0.4, -0.55, 0 left norotate back textcolor rgb "green"  nopoint offset character 0, 0, 0
set label 5 "plot ... lt 1 lc 3 lw 3" at -0.4, -0.65, 0 left norotate back textcolor lt 3 nopoint offset character 0, 0, 0
set label 6 "plot ... lt 3 lc 3 lw 2" at -0.4, -0.75, 0 left norotate back textcolor lt 3 nopoint offset character 0, 0, 0
set label 7 "plot ... lt 5 lc 3 lw 3" at -0.4, -0.85, 0 left norotate back textcolor lt 3 nopoint offset character 0, 0, 0
set style line 1  linetype 2 linecolor rgb "red"  linewidth 3.000 pointtype 1 pointsize default
set style line 2  linetype 2 linecolor rgb "orange"  linewidth 2.000 pointtype 2 pointsize default
set style line 3  linetype 2 linecolor rgb "yellow"  linewidth 3.000 pointtype 3 pointsize default
set style line 4  linetype 2 linecolor rgb "green"  linewidth 2.000 pointtype 4 pointsize default
set noxtics
set noytics
set title "Independent colors and dot/dash styles" 
set xlabel "You will only see dashed lines if your current terminal setting permits it" 
set xrange [ -0.500000 : 3.50000 ] noreverse nowriteback
set yrange [ -1.00000 : 1.40000 ] noreverse nowriteback
set bmargin  7
unset colorbox
plot cos(x)     ls 1 title 'ls 1',        cos(x-.2)  ls 2 title 'ls 2',     cos(x-.4)  ls 3 title 'ls 3',     cos(x-.6)  ls 4 title 'ls 4',      cos(x-.8)  lt 1 lc 3 title 'lt 1 lc 3',       cos(x-1.)  lt 3 lc 3 title 'lt 3 lc 3',       cos(x-1.2) lt 5 lc 3 title 'lt 5 lc 3'
```

The code above plots the picture below, but the curves are supposed to be dashed.

[image]

Comment: Some additional information about dashed lines https://stackoverflow.com/a/19420678/2604213

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell gnuplot that the lines should be dashed. You do this via `dashtype` or `dt`.

```
...
cos(x-.8)  dt 2 lt 1 lc 3 title 'lt 1 lc 3', \
cos(x-1.)  dt 3 lt 3 lc 3 title 'lt 3 lc 3', \
cos(x-1.2) dt 4 lt 5 lc 3 title 'lt 5 lc 3'
```

[image]